# Set Socket Options On Python Asyncio Streams API

Tags: python, sockets, python-asyncio

Im using the asyncio streams API to create a socket connection. Is there a way I can set options such as keep alive setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_KEEPALIVE, 1) ?

I see from the docs that [`asyncio.open_connection`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html#asyncio.open_connection) transfers ownership of the socket over to the streamwrite and the socket object can be closed after, Im unclear if those options get ported over as well.

Am I missing out on something obvious ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The socket is available through [asyncio.StreamWriter.get_extra_info](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html). You can set socket options using [socket.setsockopt](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html) from there. Something like:

```
reader, writer = await asyncio.open_connection(host=host, port=port)
sock = writer.get_extra_info("socket")

sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_KEEPALIVE, True)
sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_KEEPIDLE, idle)
sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_KEEPINTVL, interval)
sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_KEEPCNT, count)
```